# When I use react router with webpack, it shows the error "React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpack and React</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">hello</div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router";

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Featured from "./pages/Featured";
import Archives from "./pages/Archives";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDom.render(
    <Router>
            <Route path = "/" component={Layout}/>
    </Router>,
    app);
```

Layout.js

```
import React from "react";


export default class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Discussion Board</h1>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I follow the online example to learn react router with webpack but it shows the error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your 
component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I cannot find what reason to cause the error. Someone said that I might not add the export default but I have already added it. It is still error.

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with the `id` of `app` in your html ?

Comment: @dev_junwen ys, it has id in the index.html. Also, this error only appears if I used react router.

Comment: How about your `Featured`, `Archives` and `Settings` component? Did you include them in your routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router";
```

should be

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

A note from the `react-router` npm package page:

> **Note:** This package provides the core routing functionality for React Router, but you might not want to install it directly. If you are writing an application that will run in the browser, you should instead install `react-router-dom`. Similarly, if you are writing a React Native application, you should instead install `react-router-native`. Both of those will install `react-router` as a dependency.

Comment: you solved my problem!! But why will be this? The example is "from "react-router""

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a reference for your query

Comment: react-router is a base implementation. `react-router-dom` is a wrapper around `react-router` to run in the browser.